# How do you set the avatar of API-triggered messages?

Tags: node.js, slack-api

Looking at the [slack api](https://api.slack.com/), I can't see any way to set the avatar of things posted through the API, although they show many examples of api messages coming with avatars, like this

[image]

I'm using `chat.postMessage` to post messages as my app. I can alter the username, but I can't figure out any way to set the icon.

My posts just end up looking like this:

[image]

Comment: You configure the avatar in the slack bot settings.

Comment: @tymeJV and where are these settings located? Also, I'm not using a bot, I'm using an access token to post.

Comment: Sorry - got pulled away from my desk. If you're just sending a request to a web hook - supply the `icon_emoji` property: `"icon_emoji":":ghost"`

Comment: @tymeJV Thanks. I wanted to use my own image rather than an emoji, so instead of setting `icon_emoji`, I set `icon_url` to a link to an image, and it appeared as the bot's avatar! If you set that as an answer, I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending messages through a web-request - you can supply the `icon_emoji` property with a supported emoji name, such as:

```
{
    ..
    "icon_emoji":":ghost"
}
```

Or, with an `icon_url` property:

```
{
    ..
    "icon_url":"<your valid url>"
}
```